# Undeclared identifier customActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am implementing an `IBAction` but I see a warning message of an *undeclared identifier* and I don't know how to remove it.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)showGCOptions:(id)sender {

         [_customActionSheet showInView:self.view
         withCompletionHandler:^(NSString *buttonTitle, NSInteger buttonIndex) {

             if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"View Leaderboard"]) {
                 [self showLeaderboardAndAchievements:YES];
             }
             else if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"View Achievements"]) {
                 [self showLeaderboardAndAchievements:NO];
             }
             else{

             }
         }];

     }
```

On the second line where it says `_customActionSheet` I see warning about an

> undeclared identifier `_customActionSheet`

Please help how to fix it. Thanks thank you

Comment: whether u declare _customactionsheet?

Comment: No i have not declared it I need help declaring identifiers I am new to xcode and I am following a tutorial for implementing Game Center.

Comment: You haven't declared `_customActionSheet` and you are asking why you are getting it and how to fix it? How are we possibly meant to know what `customActionSheet` is? Is this an instance of `UIActionSheet` or is this some third part custom action sheet? This question lacks so much information for us to possibly help you. We can only provide answers based on assumptions which isn't what stackoverflow is about. -1 and vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare either in the header file:

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController {
    UIActionSheet *_customActionSheet;
}
...
@end
```

Or privately within the implementation file using a private category:

```
@interface YourClass () {
    UIActionSheet *_customActionSheet;
}
@end
@implementation YourClass
...
@end
```

I would favour the latter.

Now a word about the code you posted; it uses the button titles to identify the choice made by the user and that is a bad idea as it will hamper internationalization of your app, where the buttons will have different text.  Instead use the buttonIndex:

```
[_customActionSheet showInView:self.view
         withCompletionHandler:^(NSString *buttonTitle, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
             [self showLeaderboardAndAchievements:buttonIndex == 0];
         }];
```

Comment: Yess I tried to declare and also used the method you specified above but it still gives error saying "No visible@interface for 'UIActionSheet' declares the selector 'showInView:withCompletionHandler.' I am stuck ...

Answer (score 0):

**Question1** undeclared identifier _customActionSheet

**Compiler Says** You are using _customActionSheet in a method, but i didn't find any declaration on local/global scope.

**Question2** No visible@interface for 'UIActionSheet' declares the selector 'showInView:withCompletionHandler.

**Compiler Says** First of all i didn't know who is _customActionSheet, so where can i find out that method to execute on it''showInView:withCompletionHandler'.Common declare the customActionSheet object type then specify the method declaration on .h file. Then only i knew about that method. otherwise i will raise warnings.

**Solution**

In YourViewController.m **#import "CustomActionSheet.h"**

In YourViewController.h

```
    @class CustomActionSheet
    @interface YourViewController : UIViewControl...
```

**Second**  In YourViewController.m top

```
    @interface YourViewController ()

    @property (nonatomic, strong) CustomActionSheet *customActionSheet;

    @end

    @implementation YourViewController

    ..Here goes your implementation
    @end
```

[Check this out tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-kit-framework/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that doesnt solve the problem the error is still there and in addition to this error there comes another error saying "Type of property 'customActionSheet' does not match the type of instance variable '_customActionSheet'(UIActionSheet*_strong')

Answer (score -1):

This is to initialise UIActionSheet

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"title 1",@"title 2", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view]
```